# Can I move a coffin and it's corpse?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

A dwarf died, and the room I wanted to put the coffin hadn't been mined out, and In a rush to get the corpse safely stowed away, I plonked the coffin in the hallway outside where his tomb was to be. I want to move it inside, but I don't want to click "Remove Building" for fear of it just being gotten rid of. Can I, for instance, safely select "remove building", whereupon it will be put away into the appropriate stockpile and I can place it again. With the same person in it.

Comment: All of the "remove building" commands drops whatever items they used up behind after deconstruction.

Comment: Does that mean I'll be able to re-make it exactly?

Comment: Yes. You may have to wait for a hauler dwarf to put it into a furniture stockpile, but all constructed furniture can be deconstructed and moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move a coffin and a dwarf together, but you can move them.

A constructed coffin is essential a building containing two objects: the coffin item itself and the dwarf. If you deconstruct the coffin building, both the coffin item and the dwarf corpse will be placed on the floor, then moved to stockpiles/available coffins by dwarves as appropriate and available.

You won't lose any of the parts by deconstructing it, so as long as dwarves are available and you manage what they do you can effectively move the whole thing.

Comment: So the workflow would be 1. build the new tomb with a new coffin, 2. deconstruct old coffin, 3. see how the dwarf gets moved to new tomb and the old coffin gets moved to furniture storage where it will be reusable for another dwarf?

Comment: @Philipp Yes, or if you wanted to use the same coffin specifically for the same dwarf you could forbid the corpse before deconstruction (in building contents) and then unforbid it after.

Comment: @Philipp Also you only have to forbid the corpse if you want to avoid it being put in the coffin. If there are other corpses competing for coffin space you can forbid them, too.